# SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0): Native could not create new byte[]

Tags: android, out-of-memory, ormlite

I'm getting this error when trying to query up to 30 objects, each object has **field byte[]** which weights 100x100 ARGB_8888 bitmap data **~ 39kb**

I'm using OrmLite 4.45 version. on a Samsung GT n8000 tablet (max heap size 64mb)

Here's stacktrace:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0): Native could not create new byte[]
    at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetBlob(Native Method)
    at android.database.CursorWindow.getBlob(CursorWindow.java:403)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getBlob(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:45)
    at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseResults.getBytes(AndroidDatabaseResults.java:161)
    at com.j256.ormlite.field.types.ByteArrayType.resultToSqlArg(ByteArrayType.java:41)
    at com.j256.ormlite.field.BaseFieldConverter.resultToJava(BaseFieldConverter.java:24)
    at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.resultToJava(FieldType.java:798)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.BaseMappedQuery.mapRow(BaseMappedQuery.java:60)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.getCurrent(SelectIterator.java:270)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.nextThrow(SelectIterator.java:161)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:187)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.query(BaseDaoImpl.java:263)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.EagerForeignCollection.(EagerForeignCollection.java:37)
    at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.buildForeignCollection(FieldType.java:781)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.BaseMappedQuery.mapRow(BaseMappedQuery.java:82)
    at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseConnection.queryForOne(AndroidDatabaseConnection.java:186)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedQueryForId.execute(MappedQueryForId.java:38)
    at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.assignField(FieldType.java:540)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.BaseMappedQuery.mapRow(BaseMappedQuery.java:71)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.getCurrent(SelectIterator.java:270)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.nextThrow(SelectIterator.java:161)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:187)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.query(BaseDaoImpl.java:263)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder.query(QueryBuilder.java:319)
    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.Where.query(Where.java:485)
    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.queryForEq(BaseDaoImpl.java:243)
```

here's logcat:

```
05-16 14:05:24.561: D/dalvikvm(4163): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1247K, 10% free 18046K/19911K, paused 11ms+3ms, total 30ms
05-16 14:05:24.561: D/dalvikvm(4163): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 10ms
05-16 14:05:24.686: D/dalvikvm(4163): GC_CONCURRENT freed 119K, 4% free 19922K/20743K, paused 11ms+2ms, total 28ms
05-16 14:05:24.686: D/dalvikvm(4163): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
... whole ton of these
05-16 14:05:27.261: D/dalvikvm(4163): GC_CONCURRENT freed 109K, 2% free 62754K/63495K, paused 12ms+5ms, total 36ms
05-16 14:05:27.261: D/dalvikvm(4163): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 20ms
05-16 14:05:27.366: I/dalvikvm-heap(4163): Clamp target GC heap from 65.738MB to 64.000MB
```

- **Is such fast growth of memory usage normal?**
- **What do you think about splitting query into chunks and explicitly calling System.gc() between those separate queries?**

Thanks!

Comment: In the future, please show your entities in question.  Just showing the log output doesn't provide any background on the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is such fast growth of memory usage normal?

No it isn't.

> What do you think about splitting query into chunks and explicitly calling System.gc() between those separate queries?

No, this most likely would not fix the issue.  You need to resolve the underlying memory issue directly.

After looking at your code and entities that you did not provide in your post, this is not a [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) issue but a entity problem.

You have a `Gallery` of `Photo`s.  Each photo has a possibly large array of byte image data -- maybe 50+k.  The problem is that the `Gallery` has an eager foreign collection of `Photo`s:

```
@ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)
private ForeignCollection<Photo> photos;
```

And then each `Photo` has an auto-refreshed version of its parent `Gallery`.

```
@DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, columnName = GALLERY)
private Gallery gallery;
```

This sets up an eager fetch loop which causes ORMLite to do something like the following:

1. Whenever ORMLite tries to load the `Gallery` into memory...
2. it is being asked to do another query and load all of the photos associated with the `Gallery` into memory because of the eager collection.
3. For each of those `Photo` instances, it is being asked to do another query to get the associated `Gallery` into memory because of the auto-refreshed parent.
4. And for that `Gallery` it is asked to load all of the `Photo`s into memory.
5. ...  ORMLite actually has an escape but still does this 3 levels down.

ORMLite has no magic view of the `Gallery` and `Photo` instances so it attach the parent `Gallery` to the foreign field in the `Photo`s.  If you want this then I'd see the `ObjectCache` solution below.

There are a number of ways you can fix this:

- I'd recommend *not* using `foreignAutoRefresh = true`.  If you need the `Gallery` of a photo then you can get it by doing `galleryDao.refresh(photo.getGallery())`.  This breaks the chain of eager fetches.
- You could also make the `photos` collection *not* be eager.  A lazy loaded collection would go more times to the database but would also break the cycle.
- If you *really* must have all of the eager collection and refreshing then the best solution however would be the introduction of an `ObjectCache`.  You may have to clear the cache often but each of the DAOs would then look in the cache and return the same object entity even with the eager fetch loop going on.

  ```
  galleryDao = getHelper().getRuntimeExceptionDao(Gallery.class);
  galleryDao.setObjectCache(true);
  photoDao = getHelper().getRuntimeExceptionDao(Photo.class);
  photoDao.setObjectCache(true);
  ...
  // if you load a lot of objects into memory, you must clear the cache often
  galleryDao.clearObjectCache();
  photoDao.clearObjectCache();
  ```

Comment: Gray, I've been meaning to try out ORMlite in the next big app I write. I do have a question regarding the current question, though - why do you require manual cleanup of the object cache - surely, time-based eviction would be a good middle ground? In Guava, for example, you can do `.expiresAfterRead(1, TimeUnit.MINUTE)` to evict items after last read more than a minute ago. Of course, in your case you can do more clever case-specific metrics but the point still stands - surely this should be automated?

Comment: Can you ask this question to the ormlite-users list @Delyan to others can learn from it and my answer?