# Android - dynamically change a list with an edittext error - LiveData + Room + ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room, viewmodel, android-livedata

I want to dynamically change a list based on the text of the edit text. The technique below works but when I change many times in the same activity I get an error. I think that as the changes I overload too much with the multiples to observe but I do not yet have an idea of an alternative. I specify that my list view displays photos, it is a gallery. And I don't want a search button I want this to be done live.

And another problem, when I do a search, about one in ten times one of the displayed photos does not match its source and when I display it (opening an activity that displays a single photo), the original source goes displays, or when I change a letter in the edit text, the original source comes back, really weird.

thank you in advance

Activity with edit text:

```
// RecyclerView
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 3);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.photo_album_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // ViewModel
        PhotoViewModel photoViewModel = new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(getApplication()).create(PhotoViewModel.class);
        photoViewModel.getAllPhotos().observe(PhotoAlbumActivity.this, new Observer<List<Photo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Photo> photos) {
                mAdapter.submitList(photos);
            }
        });

        edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                search = charSequence.toString().replaceAll(" ", "%");
                photoViewModel.getSearchPhotos(search).observe(PhotoAlbumActivity.this, photos -> mAdapter.submitList(photos));
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });
```

And error :

```
W/oehpad.visiopa: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 2132760 byte allocation with 2030720 free bytes and 1983KB until OOM, max allowed footprint 536870912, growth limit 536870912" (VmSize 2779292 kB)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: arch_disk_io_0
    Process: fr.visioehpad.visiopad, PID: 20843
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing database live data.
        at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:92)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0 SQLITE_OK[0]): Native could not create new byte[]
        at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetBlob(Native Method)
        at android.database.CursorWindow.getBlob(CursorWindow.java:430)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getBlob(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:45)
        at fr.visioehpad.visiopad.data.repository.PhotoDao_Impl$6.call(PhotoDao_Impl.java:375)
        at fr.visioehpad.visiopad.data.repository.PhotoDao_Impl$6.call(PhotoDao_Impl.java:354)
        at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:90)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20843 SIG: 9
```

**EDIT :**

Finally, I've found an issue, I'm using a popup for search but it's the same if I'm using EditText dinamically :

Activity :

```
// Get photos with the filter
photoViewModel.getPhotos().observe(this, new Observer<List<Photo>>() {
      @Override
      public void onChanged(List<Photo> photos) {
          mAdapter.submitList(photos);
      }
});

btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
          searchPopup = new SearchPopup(PhotoAlbumActivity.this, search, "test");
          searchPopup.setOnBtnClickListener(new SearchPopup.OnBtnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void OnValidClick(String texte) {

              // On vérifie si on laisse affiche le bouton pour annuler la recherche
              if (texte.isEmpty()){
                     btnRemoveSearch.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
              } else {
                     btnRemoveSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              }

              search = texte;
              photoViewModel.refreshData(search);
              searchPopup.dismiss();
           }
       });
    }
});
```

ViewModel :

```
private MutableLiveData<List<Photo>> photos = new MutableLiveData<>();

public MutableLiveData<List<Photo>> getPhotos(){
      return photos;
}

/**
 * Actualisation des données lors d'une nouvelle recherche.
 * @param words les mots à rechercher
 */
public void refreshData(String words) {
    ExecutorService service =  Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    service.submit(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             List<Photo> freshPhotosList = mRepository.getSearchPhotos(DataSearchUtils.getTextForSearch(words));
                photos.postValue(freshPhotosList);
         }
    });
}
```

Util for query in room (i'ven't found equivalent of CONTAINS in SQL (LIKE + IN)) :

```
public static String getTextForSearch(String search) {
    // init with percent to search all first or if search is empty
    String str = "%";
    if (!search.trim().isEmpty()) {
        str += search.replaceAll(" ", "%");
        str += "%";
    }
    return str;
}
```

Repository :

```
public List<Photo> getSearchPhotos(String chaine) {
    return mPhotoDao.getSearchPhotos(userId, chaine);
}
```

DAO :

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM photo_table " +
            "WHERE userId = :userId " +
            "AND ( (description LIKE :chaine) " +
            "OR (dateForSearch LIKE :chaine) " +
            "OR (contactFrom LIKE :chaine)) " +
            "ORDER BY date DESC")
List<Photo> getSearchPhotos(Long userId, String chaine);
```

Comment: This seems like a similar issue at first glance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585221/sqliteexception-unknown-error-code-0-native-could-not-create-new-byte

Answer (score 1):

You have to add two functions, one in the view model class and call it from the view or activity (observe) and name it (refreshAllPhotos()),
and another function in the recycler view adapter class called (updateAllPhotos()), and this function should clear all photos list every time you search in the edit text, The refresh function although should be called every time you run the activity.